# J/Link: How to run a thread inside Mathematica

Tags: java

In the J/Link User Guide there is no example on how to use java.lang.Thread,
from inside Mathematica.

I'd like to know if is possible to start a thread from a `JavaNew` object which
has a Runnable interface implemented.

If I run this code from a java main class everything works fine.
The Thread will run sampling bid/ask from a tcp/ip data stream and every time I need to know the bid/ask data I call the method that get me the value.

```
t3OpenT job01 = new t3OpenT("192.168.0.78",5333,500000,200);
        job01.openConnection();
        job01.setRequest("function=subscribe|item=MI.EQCON.1|schema=best_bsiz1;best_bid1;best_ask1;best_asiz1;symbol");
        job01.subscribeData();

System.out.println("now start the thread 01");
        Thread ntJob01 = new Thread(job01);
        ntJob01.setDaemon(true);
        ntJob01.setName("GENERALI");
        ntJob01.start();
```

But if I create the objects inside the notebook using JavaNew[....] and then start the thread it will execute but it is interrupted immediately.

Here is the mathematica code I use:

```
In[33]:= generaliGRT = t3OpenObjectT[{generaliG}]

Out[33]= {{"1", "G", JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject27681839799861249}}

(*Now we setup T3OpenObject to subscription:*)

In[34]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@
 setRequest[
  "function=subscribe|item=MI.EQCON.1|schema=best_bsiz1;best_bid1;best_ask1;\
best_asiz1;symbol"]

(*subscribe the data on GENERALI stock*)

In[35]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@subscribeData[];
generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getResponse[]

Out[36]= "outcome=OK|item=MI.EQCON.1"

(*the response is OK so now we are redy to start the thread *)

In[37]:= th = JavaNew["java.lang.Thread", generaliGRT[[1, 3]]]

Out[37]= JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject8825827030466561

th@setDaemon[True]

In[39]:= th@setName["GENERALI"]

In[40]:= th@getName[]

Out[40]= "GENERALI"

In[41]:= th@start[]

In[42]:= th@getId[]

Out[42]= 14

(*the thread is immediately terminated *)
In[43]:= th@getState[]@toString[]

Out[43]= "TERMINATED"

(*but I can read the pusched stock date*) 
In[45]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getInfo[]

Out[45]= {"MI.EQCON.1", "18387", "17.19", "17.21", "14300", "G"}
```

and here is the run() method of T3OpenT class:

```
@Override
    public void run(){

        thExtSignal = false;
        refThread = Thread.currentThread();

        try{

            while (true){

                try{
                    //check if thread must be terminated
                    if(thExtSignal == true){
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted()){
                         throw new InterruptedException();
                    }
                    //read data from buffer
                    this.pushedData = this.refBufReader.readLine();
                    //get the time stamp
                    dateTimeSample = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString();
                    //split the response end move data in a string vector
                    String responseBidAsk[] = pushedData.split("\\|", 6);
                    //update only elements tha are changed
                    for(int i=0 ; i<=responseBidAsk.length-1;i++){
                        if(responseBidAsk[i].length()>0){
                            info[i]=responseBidAsk[i];
                        }else{
                            info[i]=info[i];
                        }
                    }
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //if the thread is interrupted then unsubscribe
                    this.unsubscribe();
                    // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
                    return;        
                }
            }
        }   
        catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            //if timeout unsubscribe
            response = "timeOut";
            unsubscribe();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            pushedData = "error";

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Java, but I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. J/Link is just an interface to Java code running in the JVM, so if you can do it in Java, I suspect you should also be able to do it using J/Link. Have you tried? If so, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Yes I've tried, seems that mathematica interrupts the thread as soon as it start. I'm trying to start the Thread inside the notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Massimo, I have no problem with creating/starting/running/destroying threads explicitly using JLink:

```
Needs["JLink`"]

ReinstallJava[]

Do[
thread=JavaNew["java.lang.Thread"];
thread@start[];
Print@thread@getId[];
thread@sleep[10];
thread@stop[];
,{10}]
```

I've also shown several examples using explicit Java thread management with M code on the 2007 conference (programming a drum computer using sound samples. Every track runs in its own thread).

And you can use explicit Java code (as well as Scala, C#, and F# code, by the way) with my commercial product [JVMTools](http://jvmtools.net). Here is the [code compilation page](http://jvmtools.net/jcc.html). You can either a) put your Java, Scala, C#, or F# code into a string and get it compiled (if it doesn't compile, [JVMTools](http://jvmtools.net) exposes you the exact error messages that the compiler generates), and execute, or b) create a special cell in the M f/e specific to the type of the language you are using (again, Java, Scala, C#, or F#), and then just type your code away. It also features syntax highlighting, using the syntax highlighter from Leonid (which was included in [JVMTools](http://jvmtools.net) with his permission). Just look at the [product page](http://jvmtools.net/jcc.html), there are many simple examples that show how it's working.

Disclaimer: [JVMTools](http://jvmtools.net) is a commercial product for M sold by [Lauschke Consulting](http://lauschkeconsulting.net). I am the owner of [Lauschke Consulting](http://lauschkeconsulting.net).

Comment: Thanks Andreas, so now I try to close the thread creation inside a Do block. But the strange think is that if I write a main-Class and run the code everything works fine. So I think that I'm missing somethink on mathematica side.

Comment: Now I know the problem is SocketTimeoutException. Outside mathematica (using a java main class) this exception is never rised, but using J/Link is always raisen.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
The problem was with socketTimeOut, the value I used in mathematica was too low, but it was rigth in java main class.
If I use a value of 500000 the TimeOut is never raised and the buffer has enough time waiting new data from tcp data server.

I modified the mathematica wrapper to java class costructor and added the Option soTimeOut:

```
In[21]:= generaliGRT = t3OpenObjectT[{generaliG}, SoTimeOut -> 500000]

Out[21]= {{"1", "G", JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject24868164546330625}}

In[72]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getRefSocket[]@getSoTimeout[]

Out[72]= 500000
```

Now when I start the thread it runs in background and let the notebook ready to do other stuffs:

```
In[73]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getInfo[]

Out[73]= {"MI.EQCON.1", "29819", "17.11", "17.13", "22493", "G"}

In[74]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getInfo[]

Out[74]= {"MI.EQCON.1", "29771", "17.11", "17.13", "20191", "G"}

In[75]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getInfo[]

Out[75]= {"MI.EQCON.1", "28924", "17.11", "17.13", "20191", "G"}

In[76]:= generaliGRT[[1, 3]]@getInfo[]

Out[76]= {"MI.EQCON.1", "29781", "17.11", "17.13", "20191", "G"}
```

Thank you very much, some times one written word is enough to put someone on the rigth way